Check if coin is registrered on Raydium
What is the most efficient way to check if a Solana coin is listed on DEX in Python?
I know it can be done through dexscreener getToken API. However, I don't need any information about the token other than if it's registered on DEX or not.
As I will be doing this for a lot of tokens I wanted to look for a faster solution that would be more efficient. One approach I considered was to check if Raydium has created a token pair for the token. Is this possible to do?

To efficiently check if a Solana coin is listed on a DEX using Python, you can indeed verify if Raydium has created a token pair for the token. This can be done by querying Raydium's on-chain data or using their API if available.
Here's a step-by-step approach to achieve this:

Use Raydium's On-Chain Data:
You can query Raydium's on-chain data to check for the existence of a liquidity pool for the token. This involves checking if the token has an associated pool address on Raydium.

Query Raydium API:
If Raydium provides an API, you can use it to fetch information about liquidity pools and pairs. This can be faster and more efficient compared to manually parsing on-chain data.

Use Solana's RPC Methods:
Utilize Solana's RPC methods to query for token pairs. This can be done by checking the accounts associated with Raydium's program ID.


Here's a basic example of how you can check for a Raydium token pair using Solana's RPC methods:
import requests
import json

def check_token_pair(token_mint_address):
    url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getProgramAccounts",
        "params": [
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",  # Raydium's program ID
            {
                "encoding": "jsonParsed",
                "filters": [
                    {"dataSize": 165},
                    {"memcmp": {"offset": 0, "bytes": token_mint_address}}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json().get('result', [])
        return len(result) > 0  # Returns True if the token pair exists
    else:
        print(f"Error: Failed to fetch data with status code {response.status_code}")
        return False

# Example usage
token_mint_address = "YourTokenMintAddressHere"
is_listed = check_token_pair(token_mint_address)
print(f"Token is listed on Raydium: {is_listed}")

Explanation:

getProgramAccounts RPC method: This method queries all accounts owned by a specific program ID. In this case, it checks for accounts associated with Raydium's program ID.
Filters: The filters ensure that we are only checking for token accounts that match the specified mint address.

By using this approach, you can efficiently determine if a token is listed on Raydium. This method avoids unnecessary data fetching and focuses on the essential check for the existence of a token pair.
I hope this helps!
